# Simple xml update with php

Tags: xml

I know this discussion has already been covered, and I've tried every suggestion on here, but I can't seem to get a simple read out of an xml file from php. I'm simply trying to read a tag's contents by id. Here's the xml:

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<queries>
    <sql id="one">here is the first one</sql>
    <sql id="two">here is the second one</sql>
</queries>
```

And I'm simply trying to read with this:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse = TRUE;
$dom->loadXML('test.xml');
$node = $dom->getElementById('one');
echo $node->nodeValue;
?>
```

Why in the world can't I get this to work? Sorry for the newb question, but I'm brand new to php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ID attributes with [DOMElement::setIDAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setidattribute.php) or use a DTD which defines an attribute to be of type ID (which your example doesn't include).

Final code:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse = TRUE;
$dom->loadXML('test.xml');
$dom->setIdAttribute("id",true);
$node = $dom->getElementById('one');
echo $node->nodeValue;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got a 500 server error on this one. I'm using a Zend server. Maybe I've got some configuration wrong. I'll look around.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` doesn't work the same in PHP as it does in JavaScript and the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) will explain. If you don't want to go to the trouble of setting your IDs in code, an alternate way to "find by ID" is using XPath:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse = TRUE;
$dom->loadXML('test.xml');

$dxp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $dxp->query('//sql[@id = "one"]');
$node = $result->item(0);
echo $node->nodeValue;
?>
```